# Fragments added to linearLayout are stacking, Causing only final one added is visible

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I have a view that contains a YouTubePlayerSupportFragment, with a small box around it for styling. I want to add multiple instances of this view on top of each other (vertically) to another view. I have it working for adding a single view, but when I try to add multiple they just stack on each other, so that only the one that was added last is visible. I was able to prove this was happening, by programatically making the first view added longer and I could see the extra height of it beneath the topmost view.

Here is my code:

**fragment_youtube_video:**

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:background="#FFFFFFFF">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/youTubeVideo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:name="com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerSupportFragment" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/videoTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:text="Video" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**fragment_videos:**

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/topBar" 
        android:background="#000000"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logoImageView"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/CD_logo"
        android:src="@drawable/logo" />

    <RelativeLayout 
       android:id="@+id/pagerTitle"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_below="@+id/logoImageView"
       android:background="#80000000"
       android:paddingBottom="10dp"
       android:paddingLeft="2dp"
       android:paddingRight="2dp"
       android:paddingTop="10dp"
       android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
       android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
       android:layout_marginRight="12dp" >
    [REMOVED FOR SPACE]
    </RelativeLayout>
    <ScrollView 
        android:id="@+id/scrollableVideoBox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/pagerTitle"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/pagerTitle"
        android:layout_below="@+id/pagerTitle">
        <LinearLayout 
           android:id="@+id/videosLayout"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:orientation="vertical"
           android:background="#a0000000">
       </LinearLayout>
   </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**VideosFragment.java:**

```
private void addVideoViews() {
    int count = 0;
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

    for (String  vidURL : videoURLs) {
        new YoutubeFragment();

        YoutubeFragment player = YoutubeFragment.newInstance(count, vidURL);
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.videosLayout, player, "x_" + count);

        count++;
    }
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

I could provide more code, but I believe these are the necessary pieces. Please also feel free to let me know if I am going about this incorrectly. I am so close, I just can't figure out for the life of me why they are stacking.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We went into Chat, and this is what we came to:

```
LinearLayout parentLayout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.videosLayout); 
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(); 
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction(); 
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()); 

for (String vidURL : videoURLs) { 
final String vidUrl2 = vidURL; 
LinearLayout placeholder = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_youtube_video, container, false); 
View youtuber = placeholder.findViewById(R.id.youTubeVideo); 
YouTubePlayerSupportFragment player = new YouTubePlayerSupportFragment(); 
fragmentTransaction.add(youtuber.getId(), player); 
placeholder.setId(12345); 
parentLayout.addView(placeholder); 

player.initialize("secret", new OnInitializedListener() { 

@Override 
public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider arg0, YouTubePlayer arg1, 
boolean arg2) { 
if (!arg2) { 
arg1.cueVideo(vidUrl2); 
} 
    } 

    @Override 

public void onInitializationFailure(Provider arg0, 
YouTubeInitializationResult arg1) { 

} 
}); 
} 
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Placeholder is a LinearLayout with two children, a LinearLayout to hold the youtube fragment, and a TextView to hold the title.

Comment: I do not know the exact amount. It will likely be between 1-10. I guess I could add 10 or so and do it that way. I was hoping to keep it more dynamic though. Could I add those placeholder views dynamically?

Comment: I tried to use the code in the linked example, but it still results in them being stacked. This has me inclined to believe I have a layout issue somewhere.

Comment: Yea that would be the most likely culprit.  If you put placeholders in does that work correctly?  If that works right, then atleast you have a correct way to get them in line.

Comment: One good way do this would be to create a view:

Placeholder.xml which is just a linear layout or view with the styling.  Whenever you want to add one just create this view, tag it, add it to your larger holder, then put your fragment in that view.

Comment: So, would I just keep my fragment_youtube_video.xml file (the one with the fragment) and then inflate it inside my VideosFragment.java. After inflating an instance, I would just add it to the linearLayout. I do something similar elsewhere, so this makes sense. But how do you grab the fragment when inflating the view in this manner?

Comment: Wait until the view in inflated and added, then acces it by resource after the fact and when you create your youtube instance pass it in as the attached view (as you were doing previously)

Comment: That makes a great deal of sense. Thanks for that idea. I am having an issue inflating the view (issue with the fragment it seems). Once that is fixed, I will report back (unless you see the issue there as well haha).
`LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
   

View ytVidView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_youtube_video, (ViewGroup) view.getParent(), false);`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43293/discussion-between-nathaniel-waggoner-and-pfranchise)

Comment: One thing not mentioned in the above solution is that you should set the Id of youtuber after creating it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming, that when you add multiple videos, you're just swapping them within your fragment. There aren't multiple fragments, so only one video would ever show at any given time.

I think you should use a ListView instead, that way, you can populate it with numerous videos that all have the same general layout resource. Hopefully this helps.